# How to get back deleted rows from datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using datatable and deleting multiple rows on the click of button now I'm trying to get back deleted rows from the datatable, below are the code I have written to reset the table but its not working, kindly help on this.

```
<html>
<head>      
<script>  
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#scmJobs').DataTable({
         "paging":   false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "info":     false
    });

    $('#scmJobs tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    } );

    $('#deleteButton').click( function () {
       // alert( table.rows('.selected').data().length +' row(s) selected' );
       table.rows('.selected').cache();
        table.rows('.selected').remove().draw( false );
    } );

      $('#resetButton').click( function () {
         $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
    table.draw();   
    } );

} );

 </script>
</head>
<body>

                    <input type="button" id="deleteButton" value="Delete"/> 
                    <input type="button" id="resetButton" value="Reset"/>   
                       <table id="scmJobs" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
                    class="grid" width="100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr style="background-color: silver;"  >
                                <th style="text-align:left;" width="183px"  >Attribute</th> 
                                <th width="76px">DQ</th>     
                                <th width="76px">QTY</th>    
                                <th width="77px"> DQ</th>    
                                <th width="77px">QTY </th>  
                                <th width="77px">DQ</th>    
                                 <th width="77px">QTY</th>
                                 <th width="77px">DQ</th>
                                 <th width="77px">QTY</th>
                                 <th width="77px">DQ</th>
                                 <th width="77px">QTY</th>   
                                 <th width="74px">DQ</th>   
                                 <th width="74px" >QTY </th>     


                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr  data-user="End of new attach date">
                                <td style="text-align:left;">End of new attach date</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right;">100.000</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right;">9000000000</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right;">100.000</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right;">9000000000</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right;">100.000</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right;">9000000000</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right;">100.000</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right;">9000000000</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right;">100.000</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right;">9000000000</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right;">100.000</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right;">9000000000</td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr  data-user="Contract bill-to">
                                <td style="text-align:left;">Contract bill-to</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right;">0.999907</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right;">89139</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right;">0.999907</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right;">89139</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right;">0.999907</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right;">89139</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right;">0.999907</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right;">89139</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right;">0.999907</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right;">89139</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right;">0.9999072</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right;">89139</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align:left;">Configuration</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right;">100.000</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right;">9000000000</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right;">100.000</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right;">9000000000</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right;">100.000</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right;">9000000000</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right;">100.000</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right;">9000000000</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right;">100.000</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right;">9000000000</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right;">100.000</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right;">9000000000</td>

                            </tr>

                        </tbody>
                      </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[From DataTables row().remove() API](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().remove()): "This method (and its plural counterpart, rows().remove()) will remove the selected row from the DataTable completely, deleting the allocated memory for data and node from the browser."

Solution A) Refresh the page on reset and make sure the server serves up the original version.

Solution B) Create a Recycle Bin array or a hidden table and move the rows there instead of `remove()`. Then on `$('#resetButton').click()` move them or add them back. Make sure to clear the recycle bin when reset is clicked.